# MongoDB: Query nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array

I have been reading through old answers here to try to find a solution to this - but I haven't been successful.

I have a field in a document that has a nested array as follows:

```
[tags] => Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( [_id] => 5271318ea7d63ba9a25045ad 
                      [name] => photo ) 
       [1] => Array ( [_id] => 526ffafba7d63ba9a25045a9 
                      [name] => beach ) 
       [2] => Array ( [_id] => 5271318ea7d63ba9a25045ac 
                      [name] => landscape ) 
)
```

I'm looking for documents that have **all** of the required tag id's in the search query. I have this query, but it returns all of the documents that have **any** of the id's.

```
{"tags":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":{"$in":["5271318ea7d63ba9a25045ad","526ffafba7d63ba9a25045a9"]}}}}
```

If I change the query from **$in** to **$all** it does not return anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Queries using `$in` and `$all` don't quite work the same.

```
{"tags": { $all: [
    {"$elemMatch": {"_id": "5271318ea7d63ba9a25045ad"}},
    {"$elemMatch": {"_id": "526ffafba7d63ba9a25045a9"}}]
}}
```

[Here's an example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)