# How to fetch Nested Arrays from document using PHP Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

Here I have two documents in that I need query to get `title="post one"` and `comments: userid="1"` i want to get only the comments with above criteria. not all comments.

` {
   "_id": ObjectId("53b7f2383ed7755c2400002e"),
   "title": "Post One",
   "author": "bob",
   "posted": ISODate("2014-07-05T12:40:24.0Z"),
   "pageViews": NumberInt(5),
   "comments": {
     "0": {
       "userid": "1",
       "text": "this is cool"
    },
     "1": {
       "userid": "2",
       "text": "this is bad"
    },
     "3": {
       "userid": "3",
       "text": "this is badexample"
    }
    "4": {
       "userid": "4",
       "text": "No Thanx"
    }
    "5": {
       "userid": "1",
       "text": "No Its Fine"
    }
    "6": {
       "userid": "1",
       "text": "Testing"
    }
    "7": {
       "userid": "1",
       "text": "No Its Fine ok not bad"
    }
    "8": {
       "userid": "1",
       "text": "Testing ddd"
    }

}
}
`

`{
   "_id": ObjectId("53b7f2383ed7755c2400002e"),
   "title": "Post Two",
   "author": "bob",
   "posted": ISODate("2014-07-05T12:40:24.0Z"),
   "pageViews": NumberInt(5),
   "comments": {
     "0": {
       "userid": "1",
       "text": "this is cool"
    },
     "1": {
       "userid": "2",
       "text": "this is bad"
    },
     "3": {
       "userid": "3",
       "text": "this is badexample"
    }
    "4": {
       "userid": "4",
       "text": "No Thanx"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: For some relevant discussion see: [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in documents can be queried like this

```
db.posts.findOne({comments: { $elemMatch: { userid: 1}}, 'title':"post one"});
```

For more information see these questions:

- [MongoDB nested array query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303833/mongodb-nested-array-query)
- [MongoDB: Query nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694821/mongodb-query-nested-arrays)

Comment: Note that `$elemMatch` will only return the first matching element in an array for each document. So this won't work if you want to get all the comments matching `{ userid: 1 }` in the post with `{ 'title' : "post one" }`.

Comment: I need only comments posted by only userid '1' and "title" is "Post One" not all documents

Comment: i tested but not executed i don't need all nested array i need matched nested records  only.